# Java Spring project without Entry Point

Tags: java, spring, github, jar, war

When trying to use some Spring projects from GitHub, I come across the fact that the project does not have a file with an entry point (public statics main), the question is how to launch such projects?

[image]

Comment: Can you please link the repository?

Answer (score 1):

If the project is required to be packaged as a WAR and deployed to an application server for running , the "static main" entry point is from the application server but not your application.

In case of Tomcat , it is in the class of [`org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap`](https://github.com/apache/tomcat/blob/81e721526d4125e68e591dddf14dbb460f02f43b/java/org/apache/catalina/startup/Bootstrap.java#L436)

Answer (score 0):

It depends how you going to run your application.
If you just want to run your project under some IDE or `JAR` file, declaring following `main` method should be enough:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class BackendServerApplication {

    public static void main(String [] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(BackendServerApplication.class);
    }
}
```

where `BackendServerApplication.class` is the 'entry point' class.

If you need to deploy your application from a `WAR` file, you have to extend `SpringBootServletInitializer` class as well, but keep in mind that `main` method is not invoked (because, as Ken Chan mentioned, entry point is from the application server but not your application). You can learn more from [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.1.RELEASE/reference/html/howto-traditional-deployment.html) and [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-war-tomcat-deploy).

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class BackendServerApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(String [] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(BackendServerApplication.class);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, i will try :)

Comment: I am sorry that if an existing project is not a spring boot application (which I think it is not , otherwise the OP should already find the main class)  , migrating it to a spring-boot project is not simply by just adding an `@SpringBootApplication` class  , you have to do much much more than that for the migration.